# why nodejs code is not properly reading files?

Tags: node.js, filestream

I have a nodejs file, where i read data from a file(mostly pdf and docx file). The data occured after file reading is corrupted, actually it is not in human readable form.

```
    var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream('./public/docs/'+req.file.filename);
        myReadStream.setEncoding('UTF8');
        var rContents = '' // to hold the read contents;
        myReadStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
                rContents += chunk;
        });
        myReadStream.on('error', function(err){
                console.log(err);
        });
        myReadStream.on('end', async function(){

                     console.log(rContents); //its prints unreadable output
                });
```

The output will look like this :

```
�(����j�0E����Ѷ�J�(��ɢ�eh��4ND�B�����81�$14�� ��{�1��ښl �w%�=���^i7+���-d&�0�A�6�l4��L60#�Ò�S
O����X��*��V$:�B~���^�K����ڃ
/P��I��~7$��i��J&B0Z�Du�t�OJ�K(H����xG
�L�+�v����dcӻ���W>*��\XR�mp���Z}����HwnM�V��n���-�")/�ZwB`���4���   ��s�DX���j��;A*ʝ����c�֝��4���[�S
```

Comment: It's because pdf and docx file are not just UTF8 encoded. You have styling, font embedding, compression applied, etc...

You can use this `fs` to read "simple" files. Files you are trying to read are complex and would be same if you tried to read for example `.png` and output it as text, you would see something that is not human readable

Comment: any solution where i can read complex files???@MiroslavSaracevic

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=pdf might be good start

Comment: Thank You@MiroslavSaracevic

Comment: Neither PDF nor docx are human readable. PDF are readable only to pdf readers and docx are readable to either MS word compatible reader (like google docs) or a zip file reader (because docx files are actually zip files containing a folder of XML files)